# Making php code run every couple of seconds

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a way of making my php code run every couple of seconds I need it to echo the contents of a column onto my html page but I cant work out for the life of me to get it to do it every couple of seconds or to do it when ever the database gets updated for example if the database gets a new value then run my code.

Thank You,
Lees

Comment: Depends on your use case, but research the terms "AJAX polling" and "websockets". A bit about it can be read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642598/short-polling-vs-long-polling-for-real-time-web-applications).

Comment: There are no promising attempts known to implement such feature in pure server side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to run PHP code after specific time there's two ways:
1- You can create CRON JOB
2- You can use task scheduler to run code see this post (Recommended)

[Do a PHP task every 1 minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236309/wamp-do-a-php-task-every-1-minute)

Comment: A cron job doesn't run "_every couple of seconds_" though, minimum is minutes

Comment: That's why I recommended task scheduler method.

Comment: But you also suggested cron jobs. You added the recommendation just now, _after_ I commented

Answer (score -1):

watch -n 2 /usr/bin/php PATH_TO_SCRIPT

Comment: Please add some context to your solution

Comment: @SteveT _Tester is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification_ Pay some respect lol

Comment: @Tester i dont see anything wrong with asking for more context in that way.